# how to update Witcher 3 on GoG

Tags: the-witcher-3, gog

I bought Witcher 3 in a local store at the time, so I installed it through discs. I've noticed the game hasn't updated since then though. In-game it says I'm still at version 1.02, though the changelog of the GoG Galaxy program talks about version 1.08 being implemented already.

Does anybody know how I can update Witcher 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want automatic updates you have to create an account on GOG.com either from Galaxy client you use to launch the game or via GOG.com website. After creating an account you will also have to redeem the code you got on retail box of your Witcher 3 copy.

Other method is just to download patches from http://thewitcher.com/ website.

Comment: Ah yes, I just forgot to redeem my code on the physical game on GoG. Feels pretty damn silly. Thanks for the help